# allowing cloudformation in one region to access a lambda backed custom resource in a different region

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have a lambda backed custom resource in us-east-2.  When I run a cloudformation template in us-east-2 it works just fine.  When I go to us-east-1 and try the same cloudformation template, I get an error:

```
Function not found: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:account-id:function:func_name (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 404; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException;
```

There is VPC peering between the two VPCs, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.  And when I try to deploy the same function in the same account in a different region, I get an error, I need to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think it is possible for a CloudFormation template in one Region to refer to a Lambda Custom Resource in another Region.

You will need to duplicate the function in any region where you wish it to be used as a Custom Resource.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of.  So I guess I can just tack on the region to the function name like function-us-east-1 and then I can at least use a !Join to build the Arn.  Darn it.

Comment: Would taking an SNS approach here be of any benefit?

Comment: Using an Amazon SNS topic allows you to manage subscribers who will receive the message. It also simplifies the message-sending process because the AWS Lambda function could simply send a message to the SNS topic rather than having to send an email to Amazon SES together with a list of recipients.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that, but the only way to do it is by replicating the exact same resources (via cfn) in multiple regions. I believe the best option would be to have all the resources provisioned in a generic way using cloud-formation, so that you can simply deploy it in multiple regions whenever needed.

What I mean by generic is that, do not hard code any aws environment related details or system level variables but pass the values for those variables into the templates via the cli command when you try to create the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its possible now using the new AWS stack sets.

> A stack set lets you create stacks in AWS accounts across regions by
>   using a single AWS CloudFormation template. All the resources included
>   in each stack are defined by the stack set's AWS CloudFormation
>   template

reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/stacksets-concepts.html